Constructing a Ball Containing a Convex Compact Set $K$ but Excluding $x\notin K$ in Euclidean Space
In the linked topic Finding a Ball that containing convex compact set $K$
, but Excluding $x∉K$
a counterexample was provided in the context of normed vector spaces. However, I am wondering whether this property might still hold in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$.
Specifically, if $K$ is a convex compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $x \notin K$, is it always possible to construct a ball (or sphere) that contains $K$ but excludes $x$
?
If this is true, how can such a ball be constructed?
